# Calls after call in windows batch does not show

Tags: python, batch, batch-file

I have a batch file like this for creating and activating a python virtual environment and installing some packages

create.bat:

```
mkdir "%CD%\.venv"
python -m venv .venv
call .venv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

The third line is a batch file run using the batch's call command. What I get is this:

```
E:\test>create.bat

E:\test>mkdir "E:\test\.venv"

E:\test>python -m venv .venv

E:\test>call .venv\Scripts\activate
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.0.3
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2
```

However, as you can see, when running the last line I don't see the typical prompt text that I expected:

```
...
(.venv) E:\test\> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

It just prints the output of the remaining of the operations. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but one of the tasks later on is a Python script that asks for input, but everything is ignored and runs without asking.

For reference, I'm adding the output if I type the commands manually one by one:

```
E:\test>mkdir "%CD%\.venv"

E:\test>python -m venv .venv

E:\test>call .venv\Scripts\activate

(.venv) E:\test>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.0.3
Successfully installed pip-20.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. I didn't think of it too much as the batch script I called was an autogenerated script from Python. But it included the line

```
@echo off
```

at the beginning. This command was of course still active when it returned to my script again. Solved by rewriting script to:

```
mkdir "%CD%\.venv"
python -m venv .venv
call .venv\Scripts\activate
@echo on
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```